# Spot this CSS bug?

Tags: css

I have a rounded button that I simply want the standard hover effect (hover color changes when hovered over).

The hover effect itself works fine, the issue is when I *click* the button, an outer border shows up, and sticks there until I click outside the button.

Here's a quick screencast of it happening. [Link](http://screencast.com/t/iQlDjpFWY3g)

And here's the full CSS that is currently being used: [Pastebin Link](http://pastebin.com/b1x5gr8f)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the outline property. Try adding to your button:

```
outline:none;
```

Comment: You nailed it, ty. I will accept your answer as soon as SO lets me.

Answer (score 0):

Just add outline:none;

```
.rounded {background: #fff;
margin-top: 20px;
border-radius: 20px;
-moz-border-radius: 20px;
-webkit-border-radius: 20px;
-khtml-border-radius: 20px;
outline:none; }
```